# Intel xdk share audio file

Tags: android, cordova, audio, phonegap-plugins, intel-xdk

I'm trying to share a local .mp3 file, located in 'www/audio/file.mp3' using the [socialSharing plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#4b-usage-on-windows-phone) on Android.
I built the .apk and it correctly send text and images, but when i try to share an audio, the client app(eg: Whatsapp, telegram) says that the file is not an image.
I'm using this:

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.share(null, null, 'www/audio/myAudio.mp3');
```

Comment: it says that the file is not a image do you have a screenshot???

Comment: The only thing I found about using audio files with this plugin was this  one reporting a bug like you're seeing - https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/165 - but it was enhanced last year.  I didn't notice anyone successfully using it, so maybe it's not quite working?  Might try submitting a bug on github.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved.
Plugin is broken, because it set all files as images.
So you have to download the plugin, edit locally and import as a third party plugin.
You have to edit this file `/src/android/nl/xservices/plugins/SocialSharing.java`

Search for getFileUriAndSetType function and edit this 2 lines:

```
sendIntent.setType("image/*");
```

to

```
sendIntent.setType("audio/*");
```

and

```
if (!image.contains("data:image/")) {
```

to

```
if (!image.contains("data:audio/")) {
```

After this edit all files will be sent as audio file.

Comment: I did the changes here, but still not working for me. How are you passing the file when calling shareviawhatsapp?
I followes these steps:
-install plugin via cordova plugin add
-edit SocialSharing.java
-call ionic run android

I'm using ng-cordova to wrap the plugin call